# ASP.NET Web API with OAuth2 - "Remember this browser" when using two factor authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

In the default template for ASP.NET MVC 5, there is the option of selecting "Remember this browser" when logging in using two factor authentication.

In ASP.NET MVC, this involves configuring `app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie();` in `Startup.Auth.cs` and then using `SignInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync()` with `isPersistent: true`

I would like to accomplish the same but using ASP.NET Web API with OAuth2 Bearer Tokens.

I.e. I would like the user to be able to log out (or be auto logged out). But the next time when logging in using the same browser, the user only has to provide the password, not two factor authentication.

How would I go about implementing such behavior using OAuth2 Bearer Tokens?

Comment: Why do you have two factor auth set up if you don't want to use it?

Comment: I want users to have to use two factor auth once per device (in practice, once per browser). This is the approach taken by many services -- Microsoft Account, Dropbox, etc.

Comment: You are going to need a bit field, 0 or 1, in the users table that flags the user as having successfully used the two factor auth. Then on login check that value. If they have  successfully used the two factor auth then let them in if not then send them the auth code to their device.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in my opinion it's the client side's issue and I would like to rephrase your question into "What is the best place to store authentication tokens in client side?"

You have a couple of options:

1. HTML5 Web Storage (localStorage or sessionStorage)
2. Cookies

With option one, when the tab/browser is closed the token is still alive and next time you are automatically logged in.

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem('userInfo-token', 'tokenData');
```

With option two you can save the token into a cookie and retrieve it when you are going to send a request to the server.

Of course both options have pros and cons, for more information I recommend you reading [Where to Store your JWTs – Cookies vs HTML5 Web Storage](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I would like the user to be able to log out (or be auto logged out). But the next time when logging in using the same browser, the user only has to provide the password, not two factor authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you need to take more control of the authentication solution and implement your own LoginController with a different login implementation with a "remember this browser" cookie that you create, after a successful ASP.NET Web API OAuth2 Bearer Tokens login exists, on the users browser. Just like ASP.NET MVC app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie() does.

If the user logs in with two factor, then logs out,you place a cookie on that browser,"remember me for 30 days" cookie,next time they login,you check for the unexpired cookie and allow login with password only to a different login method other than OAuth2 Bearer Tokens.

You are in control and you do not need ASP.NET Web API OAuth2 Bearer Tokens to solve your entire login solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is in control of the identity provider that you are using to authenticate the user. e.g. if you use any of the microsoft services the firs time login on the browser asks for two factor authentication and then "remembers" the browser/device for any subsequent login and doesn't kick in two factor authentication. OAuth2 is only an authorization process and not an authentication process so its unlikely you can indicate identity provider to not initiate two factor authentication.

Answer (score 0):

These are the things you can do to achieve this behavior.

1) During login button click send an ajax post request to http://{yoursite}/token. On successful login it will respond back with bearer token and some identity information. Check the "twofactorrequired" flag in local storage and identify two factor authentication is required or not. If this flag doesn't available set the flag (first login) to true. If this flag value is false that means two factor authentication is completed. One should set this flag based on email link sent to user or code to phone.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Token",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (response) {
            var json = JSON.parse(response);
            localStorage.setItem("accesstoken", json["access_token"]);

            if (isTwoFactorRequired() != false)
            {
            localStorage.setItem("twofactorrequired", true);   
            }

            window.location.href = "/Home/Index";           
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
        }
    });


function isTwoFactorRequired() {
if (localStorage.getItem("twofactorrequired") == false) {    
return false;
}
else {
return true;
}
```

**NOTE:** This method is not secure fully. One can set this flag easily using developer tools (F12). To make this more secure need to keep this flag in db along with MAC address or something like that.